# Find PDF of $Y = |X|$ if $X$ is a random variable following the normal distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

so I have a $X$ random variable, with a PDF that follows the normal distribution $X \sim N(0,1)$ so $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt (2\pi)}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$. I now have to compute the PDF of the random variable $Y = |X|$.

I started by: $F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(|X| \leq y) = \mathbb{P}( -y \leq X \leq y) = F_X(y) - F_X(-y) \Rightarrow f_Y(y) = \frac{dF_Y(y)}{dy} = \\ f_X(y)\frac{dy}{dy}-f_X(-y)|\frac{d(-y)}{dy}|$.

Is it correct to put absolute values there, or should I let the negative sign affect the sign of f_X(-y)? My teacher used to put absolute values there, but never talked about why that's useful. I could gladly use an explanation!

If I continue this way I end up with: $\frac{1}{\sqrt (2\pi)}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt (2\pi)}e^{\frac{-(-y)^2}{2}} = 0$ and I don't know if what I am doing is right. Thanks =)

Comment: I think you are mixing up with Jacobian method where you directly find PDF of $Y$ from $X$. Jacobian of change of variable is always positive so we go with $|J|$. In this case, you are differentiating CDF to obtain PDF. You should not have absolute value. The pdf of $Y$ is just $2$ times the pdf of $X$.

Comment: It is the [folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct to put absolute values there,

No, it is not quite correct.  You let the negations cancel to give you:

$$\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= ( f_X(y) - f_X(-y)\,(-1)) ~\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y}\\[2ex] &= ( f_X(y) + f_X(-y)) ~\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y}\\[2ex]&=2~f_X(y)~\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y}\end{align}$$

Which should make sense, since the support for $f_X$ is folded along the distribution's point of symmetry.  You should anticipate that the density of $Y$ will be twice that of $X$ everywhere in that folded support.

---

> teacher used to put absolute values there, but never talked about why that's useful.

There is a rigorous explanation ...but, basically... it's a cheat.  By always *adding* unsigned derivatives of the cummulative distribution from each fold, you don't have to worry about determining the direction of those folds.  You ensure all negatives cancel where the need to, so the density is always non-negative.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have 2 additional questions. 
Firstly, will folding the pdfs ( I mean having Y = |X| ) always produce Y to have twice the  density of X? 
Secondly, you mention it is a *cheat*, however it produces a wrong result if you do this in the above example. So where would it be right to use it? Or should I just forget about it?

Comment: @average_discrete_math_enjoyer no that's not correct. $Y = |X|$ will not always produce $Y$ to have double density of $X$. The _standard_ normal distribution has symmetry about $0$ which is where $Y = |X|$ folds. As a counter-example, take a density function of the form $f_X(x) = px^2 + qx + r, - a \lt x \lt b$ ($a, b \gt 0$). It is a counter-example even if $a = b$.

Comment: Indeed.  It is exactly the symmetry of $f_X(y)=f_X(-y)$, for all $y$, that produces the doubling when folding $Y=\lvert X\rvert$

Comment: @average_discrete_math_enjoyer   **Adding** the unsigned derivatives for the folds' CDF produces the correct result.$$\small f_Y(y) = \left(\left\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d F_X(y)}{\mathrm dy}\right\rvert+\left\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d F_X(-y)}{\mathrm dy}\right\rvert\right)\mathbf 1_{0<y}$$